# Tauri 'dev' and 'build' failed on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, tauri

I'm trying to build tauri app on Ubuntu 16.4.7 (LTS) by official documentation and after `sudo npm run tauri dev` or `sudo npm run tauri build` command i have many errors. Log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'tauri', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.2.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretauri', 'tauri', 'posttauri' ]
5 info lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~pretauri: tauri-app@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~pretauri: no script for pretauri, continuing
7 info lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: tauri-app@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/roman/Desktop/tauri-svelte/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: CWD: /home/roman/Desktop/tauri-svelte
11 silly lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: Args: [ '-c', 'tauri "dev"' ]
12 info lifecycle tauri-app@1.0.0~tauri: Failed to exec tauri script
13 verbose stack Error: tauri-app@1.0.0 tauri: `tauri "dev"`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:17:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid tauri-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/roman/Desktop/tauri-svelte
16 error Linux 4.15.0-142-generic
17 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "tauri" "dev"
18 error node v4.2.6
19 error npm  v3.5.2
20 error file sh
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error syscall spawn
24 error tauri-app@1.0.0 tauri: `tauri "dev"`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the tauri-app@1.0.0 tauri script 'tauri "dev"'.
25 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
25 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tauri-app package,
25 error not with npm itself.
25 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
25 error     tauri "dev"
25 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
25 error     npm bugs tauri-app
25 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
25 error     npm owner ls tauri-app
25 error There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It works on windows

```
node --version -> 17.8.0
npm --version -> 8.5.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update node and npm to the latest version.
If you have the latest version of node and npm, check whether the same version is getting picked by tauri.
When one has multiple node version, we have to specify the version to use.

Steps :

```
nvm use 18.16.1
sudo npm run tauri dev
```

nvm is a node version manager. Used to hop between multiple node versions.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve my problem by updating to a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer fails to provide verifiable information and trivializes the question.